# Check if current user is owner of GitHub remote in zsh

Tags: git, github, push, zsh, githooks

I'm trying to write a `git pre-push` hook that performs some actions prior to pushing to `origin` *if* the person pushing is the repo's owner. Is there a way to check this in `bash`/`zsh`?

Comment: This is far beyond the scope of a shell language.

Comment: @chepner Bummer. What about alternatives? The easiest would be probably then be a `node` script?

Comment: Isn’t this called authentication?

Comment: The problem is that the owner of a repo isn't well-defined. On a site like GitHub, it refers to the user account a repository is associated with. On your local machine, there isn't really an owner, just the account of the user who *clone* the remote. How do you go about determining if a local account is the same as the remote account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if the user is using HTTPS.  You'd need to use the [authenticated user endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user) to find the user ID of the current user, say, using `curl`, and then see if that user is the same as the owner of the repository by checking the URL.

To get the appropriate credentials, you can take the remote URL (e.g., `https://github.com/git/git.git`) and pipe it to `git credential fill` to find the username and password, like so:

```
echo url=https://github.com/git/git.git | git credential fill
```

The output format is defined in the `git-credential` man page.  These credentials should also be able to be used for the API to make your request, although note that since `curl` requires the password to be passed on the command line, you will expose those credentials to anyone else on the machine.  A non-shell option may be a more security-conscious choice.

Technically, there are also ways to determine this via SSH, but those rely on parsing fixed output that is subject to change, and as such, you should assume that you cannot get that information for SSH remotes.

Note that this tells you the current user, which you can check against the URL, but it doesn't tell you whether the user has administrative privileges on a repo that they don't own themselves (such as one owned by an organization).  Since you haven't told us what you want to do with this information, we can't help you out there, although if you're trying to use the API, you can just do it and see if it succeeds or not.

Since you are using the user's credential store in this case, you need to be explicit and up front with the user about what you're doing so that the user isn't surprised by your use of the credentials.  It would be unethical and probably illegal to use the user's credentials in the way I've described without their knowledge and consent.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reply, especially pointing out the downsides regarding org repos and security! I might just go with the easier option of setting up an undocumented environment variable `IS_OWNER` on the owner's machine and check for that.